# Infinitive or Preposition+Object?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, to-infinitive

**"I go to work"** may be understood in two different ways:

"Why do you go to the office so often?"  ... **I go** (*to do what?*) **to work.**

"Where do go every morning?"   ...   **I go** (*where?*) **to work.**

In this sentence is **"to work"** a to-infinitive or a preposition and an object?

Is it the same in both cases?

Comment: Does the meaning change depending on how you understand that sentence?

Comment: There are arguments that it is better to stick at the idiom analysis with the 'attend' (semelfactive or iterative) sense 'go to work / school / university  ... /  hospital ('BrE')', as 'go to infirmary / academy / recreation ...' are unacceptable. Whatever, 'work' / 'school' are certainly not verbs here. // The other interpretation uses the 'in order to [work]' / 'for the purpose of [working]' sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's strange that you answered "Where can I find you on Tuesday?" with "I go to work" while it's apparently "You can find me (where?) at work!"

Comment: Anglophones often give answers that entail the desired information (rather than largely parrot the question, or give less information than is really being sought). <<[a]  'Did you catch the weather forecast?' ... 'I'm wrapping up well when I go out, and taking an umbrella.' // [b] 'Are you hungry? ... 'I ate only an hour ago, thanks.' >> [a] 'Yes' wouldn't be helpful, and [b] 'No' would usually be considered abrupt, non-conversational.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This I know. Yet, "Where can I find you on Tuesday?" - "I go to work" sounds awkward to me.

Comment: And yet after living in England for 66 years, I'd give exactly this answer if I considered the context was right (it doubles as a hedged 'You can't, unless you are prepared to wait until after 7pm' etc). But 'This I know' _does_ sound awkward in conversation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agree. http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-much-i-know-is-true.1642085/ it actually should be "This, I know"

Comment: Disagree.  "This, I know" sounds even more awkward in conversation. It uses a formal literary style. (Or were you agreeing that my pragmatics are correct, that "I go to work [on Tuesdays]" doesn't sound awkward to native Anglophones in the UK?)

Comment: I'd say it was ambiguous, though preposition phrase is the more salient interpretation ("I go to my place of work"). Verb interpretation can be forced by adverbial postmodification, as in "I go (there) to work as a barman". In the latter interpretation "to work" would be a subordinate clause functioning as a purpose adjunct ("I go there in order to work as a barman")

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agree with both. I guess you natives understand everything much better than we non-natives do. And "This, I know" really sounds somewhat formal and more awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may refer to both the verb (to work) and to the  noun (work)

***[Go to work](http://www.yourdictionary.com/go-to-work)***:

> - To begin performing some task or work.
> - To go to one's job, as by commuting.

Dictionary.com

***[go/get to work (on someone or something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+work):***

> - to begin working on someone or something. *The masons went to work on repairing the wall. The surgeons went to work on the patient. Come on! Let's go to work!*

The Free Dictionary